# Google can't recognize Schema.org image property from Product

Tags: google-search, images, html5, microdata, schema.org

How can I use `itemprop="image"` from http://schema.org/Product so Google can recognize it in this case?

```html
<a href="#" itemprop="image" data-remote="images/portfolio/image.jpg" class="portfolio-box" data-toggle="lightbox" data-gallery="multiimages" data-title="image"></a>
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "recognize"? Show your image in a product Rich Snippet? And if yes, you are looking for a way to use an image whose URL is given in a custom `data-*` attribute of an `a` element instead of the `src` element of an `img` element? If yes, why do you want to use `a` instead of `img`?

Comment: Yes, I want to show image in a product Rich Snippet. I got it with `a` instead of `img` tag, and I must to do it through `a` tag and don't know how...

Answer (score 2):

#### According to Schema.org:

1. The [`image` property](http://schema.org/image) expects a URL or an `ImageObject` item.
2. In Microdata, [URLs must be specified with one of the HTML elements that take a URL as value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24659620/1591669). Among them is `a` (with its `href` attribute).
3. So it should be possible to use:

   ```
   <a itemprop="image" href="http://example.com/my-product-image.png">…</a>
   ```

Using custom `data-*` will most likely not work. [Per HTML5 definition](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/WD-html5-20140617/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes) they should only be used for custom data *private* to the site (and not as some kind of shared vocabulary); and anway, how should consumers like Google now what your custom attributes mean/contain?

Also, it’s clearly defined to which content an `itemprop` applies. In case of `a` it’s the `href` attribute content, not the element content, not some other attribute content.

#### According to Google:

Google doesn’t indicate how exactly their [Products Rich Snippet](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/146750?hl=en) works. Of course do they show in their examples the element that is typically used for images (`<img itemprop="image" src="anvil_executive.jpg" />`), but their examples don’t mean that it’s the *only* supported way to specify an image.